# Use formula in intervals Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get the average from different cells without manually selecting the cells.

For example:

I want to get the average of every 10 cells like this:

```
    =AVERAGE(A2:A11)
    =AVERAGE(A12:A21)
    =AVERAGE(A22:A31)
```

I have already tried the drag and drop of the formulas, however, I got the following result

```
AVERAGE(A2:A11) -> AVERAGE(A3:A12)
```

which is not the desired result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1)*10+2):INDEX(A:A,(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1)*10+11))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with ms365's new BETA-function `WRAPROWS()`:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=BYROW(WRAPROWS(A2:A31,10),LAMBDA(a,AVERAGE(a)))
```

Or, if you want something to drag down:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A,SEQUENCE(10,,(ROW(1:1)-1)*10+2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OFFSET()` and some arithmetic based on the address of each cell.

For example, if your first formula is in row 1, you can use `=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$2:$A$11,10*(ROW()-1),0))` and fill down. If you're starting in a row other than 1, change the value you're subtracting from `ROW()` accordingly.